# Appcelerator Android GCM without Appcelerator Cloud Service

Tags: android, notifications, appcelerator

I'm developing an application on Appcelerator Platform. In my android version I want to enable push notifications but I don't want to use Appcelerator Cloud Service. Could this be done using only Google Cloud Messaging?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can very well use GCM without using ACS. ACS is a service offered by Appcelerator and you may/may not choose to accept it. If using GCM, then you need to use modules to work with it.

Comment: Should I create Android module and implement the GCM there?

Comment: Yes. You need to create an Android module and implement the GCM, but there are many such modules already existing. You can search in GitHub or Appcelerator Marketplace. You can also try to use gcm.js

Answer (score 0):

ofcourse you can, the module bellow works fine

https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase-cloud-messaging